# How to draw google barchart using dynamic data from Json

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am trying to get Json data using the `$.getJSON()` method.

And this is the result:

```
Hcount:29Acount:0Pcount:12Ccount:0
```

I wanted to draw a bar chart using the result count with the help of the google chart API so I used the `getbar()` method. But nothing happenes after passing the `getbar()` method.

Here is the Javascript and HTML code:

```js
function getStats() {
 var obj1="";
 
 $.getJSON('getbusinessstats', function(response) {
 
  
  var txnSource = "";
  $.each(response.tanSource, function(key, value) {
   tanSource += key+":"+value
  });
  obj1={ "Array1": [tanSource] };
  alert(obj1.Array1)
  getbar(obj1);
  //$('#vis_div tbody').html(tanSource);
 });
 }
 
 
 
 function getbar(obj2)
 
 {
  
  google.load('visualization', '1');
       google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
 
       function drawVisualization() {
         var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
           chartType: 'ColumnChart',
           dataTable: [obj2],
                       
           options: {'title': 'INPUT'},
           containerId: 'vis_div'
         });
       
         wrapper.draw();
       }
  
 }
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
  getStats();
  setInterval(function() {
   getStats();
  }, 5000);
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div >
 <span class="label label-info">INPUT </span>
    <table id="vis_div">
     
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `getbar(boj2)` should be `getbar(obj2)`

Comment: yes that was getbar(obj2) .its type mistake. using getbar(obj2) still not able to get chart.

Comment: Missing closing head tag